# Not able push my selenium junit 5 result to kiwitcms

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I am exploring my kiwitcms with my automation,Just write simple code

```
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.kiwitcms.java.junit.KiwiTcmsExtension;

@ExtendWith(KiwiTcmsExtension.class)
public class sampleTest {
    @Test
    public void test1(){
        System.out.printf("test");
    }
    @Test
    public void test2(){
        System.out.printf("test");
    }

}
```

Here is the maven dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kiwitcms.java/kiwitcms-junit-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kiwitcms.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>kiwitcms-junit-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

**Now getting the following error**

Oct 21, 2021 4:27:12 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/jupiter/api/ClassOrderer
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.config.DefaultJupiterConfiguration.(DefaultJupiterConfiguration.java:50)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:177)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:164)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 9 more

Answer (score 1):

> I found some solution but shows error. Here is screenshot

Next time copy & paste as plain text like you've done in the first example b/c we can't comment on source code from screenshots.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\zsbap.tcms.conf (The system cannot find the file specified)

This exception is telling you that the config file is missing. (Location seems to be missing a \ though).

If you look at https://github.com/kiwitcms/junit-plugin#configuration-and-environment it says that the config file path is `~/.tcms.conf` and when you click through to the docs in
https://tcms-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms_api.html#module-tcms_api it tells us `~/` means your home directory which on Windows usually is `C:\Users\<username>\.tcms.conf`.

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander, I have updated the question and error massage. Can you please help me to solve this